# How do I pass a parameter in an asp onclick call in a table row?

Tags: asp.net, html, html-table, postback

Here I have a table row in a listview declared as follows:

```
<tr onclick="<%= _jsPostBackCall %>;" />
```

I am calling a postback method on the backend but must get the tr index:

```
    public void RaisePostBackEvent(string eventArgument)
    {
        //selected index here
    }
```

aspx page content - below is the html in the aspx page. This contains the listview.

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvEquipmentList" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="lvEquipmentList_SelectedIndexChanged" OnSelectedIndexChanging="lvEquipmentList_SelectedIndexChanging">
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <table runat="server" class="TableCSS">
                    <tr runat="server" class="TableHeader">  
                        <td runat="server" style="width: 30%;">PRODUCT LINE</td>  
                        <td runat="server" style="width: 20%;">MODEL</td>
                        <td runat="server" style="width: 20%;">SERIAL #</td>
                        <td runat="server" style="width: 12%; text-align:center">DAR STATUS</td>
                        <td runat="server" style="width: 18%; text-align:right;">SHIP DATE</td>  
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="ItemPlaceholder" runat="server">
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                <table id="Table1" runat="server" class="TableCSS">
                    <tr runat="server" class="TableHeader">  
                        <td id="Td1" runat="server" style="width: 30%;">PRODUCT LINE</td>  
                        <td id="Td2" runat="server" style="width: 20%;">MODEL</td>
                        <td id="Td3" runat="server" style="width: 20%;">SERIAL #</td>
                        <td id="Td4" runat="server" style="width: 12%; text-align:center;">DAR STATUS</td>
                        <td id="Td5" runat="server" style="width: 18%; text-align:right;">SHIP DATE</td>  
                    </tr>
                    <tr runat="server" class="TableData">
                        <td style="column-span:all;">
                            <asp:Label runat="server" Text="There are no reports to display."></asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </EmptyDataTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr style="border-bottom:1pt solid #E2E2E8;" onclick="<%= _jsPostBackCall %>;" onmouseover="this.style.background='#f6f6f6';" onmouseout="this.style.background='white'">
                    <td style="width: 30%; padding: 0px 15px 0px 15px;">
                        <table>
                            <tr class="NoBorder">
                                <td style="width: 20%;">
                                    <img src='<%#Eval("standard_image") %>' alt="" width="80" onerror="this.src='Content/Images/placeholder.png';"/>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:Label ID="lblProductLine" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("product_line")%>'/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 24%; padding: 0px 15px 0px 15px;">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblModelNum" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("model")%>'/>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 16%; padding: 0px 15px 0px 15px;">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblSerialNum" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("serial_number")%>'/>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 12%; padding: 0px 15px 0px 15px; text-align:center;">
                            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="SelectCategoryButton" CommandName="Select">
                                <img id="Img1" runat="server" src='<%#Eval("display_status") %>' alt="" width="20"/>
                            </asp:LinkButton>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 18%; padding: 0px 15px 0px 15px; text-align:right;">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblShipDate" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("date")%>'/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

When registering postback call - second argument will be the parameter:

```
_jsPostBackCall = ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this, "The Parameter");
```

Comment: How do I get the selected row index in the parameter?

Comment: You can either build the table in the backend code, then you assign the index to the callback function in the backend code as well.
Or you can loop thru table rows in client-side JavaScript modifying `onclick` function accordingly

Comment: sorry, can you post a simple example?

Comment: @KateMak do u have table already in your HTML markup or do u build it dynamically in code?

Comment: Can u also post how table looks in rendered page (fragment if table is too long)? Also are u open to use jQuery?

Comment: Sure, I could use jquery